# Why did many Hellenic or Hellenized names in antiquity end in -bazos or -dates?

Tags: ancient-history, middle-east, names

Ancient names ending with bazos (or bazus), eg megabazos(great-x), Artabazos (again great-x), Pharnabazos.

And Dates (Mithradates, Tiridates).

I know Mithra was a deity, what does the second half of the name mean (dates).

Please note I know who these people are, I'm interested in the meaning of the second part of their names.

Comment: Hellenized ancient Persian.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mithridates and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%88%CF%81%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%B2%CE%B1%CE%B6%CE%BF%CF%82